# How to make this process work faster?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, optimization

I'm trying to fill list of arrays from a large csv file (around 250 000 lines), but it's taking ages. I'm sure there is a way to make the process faster, but I don't know how !

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

energy = []
ondeIG =[]
time =[]
envelope = []

with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:        
        time = np.hstack([time, row['Time']])
        energy = np.hstack([energy, row['Energy']])
        ondeIG = np.hstack([ondeIG, row['OndeIG']])
        envelope = np.hstack([envelope, row['envelope']])
```

Thank you !

Comment: Can you post what the first few lines of your csv look like, you can probably load it much quicker using pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.hstack()` constructs a new ndarray each time which is expensive. You can update the list in-place with append:

```
with open('file.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:        
        time.append(row['Time'])
        energy.append(row['Energy'])
        ondeIG.append(row['OndeIG'])
        envelope.append(row['envelope'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To import data from csv files, have a look at pandas, and more specially at [`pandas.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)

Here you are taking tremendous time because you rebuild an array (4 arrays, even) at each iteration.